# Finding maximum Value along with another condition in Java

Tags: java

I wish to find the element with the highest value(from a list that contains all values) along with an additional condition that the maximum value must be from a particular branch_name(input from the user). There is a list that contains all the branches, its house number, value at which is was sold, etc.

I'm unable to figure out how can I add another condition(branch name) along with the maximum value.

```
 public static void highestValueSale(){

    Scanner branch = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please eneter the name of the branch, case sensitive: ");
    String branchEntered = branch.nextLine();

    double maxValue = Collections.max(Sale.allValues); //Finds the highest value from list of all values
    int indexOfMaxValue = Sale.allValues.indexOf(maxValue); //Finds index of the highest value from list of all values
    String elementOfMaxValuePostcode = (Sale.allPostcode.get(indexOfMaxValue)); // Finds the elements of same index
    int elementOfMaxValueHouseNumber = Sale.allHouseNumbers.get(indexOfMaxValue); // Finds the elements of same index

    System.out.println("The sale with highest value recorded is of house number " + elementOfMaxValueHouseNumber +
            " at postcode " + elementOfMaxValuePostcode + "." );
}
```

Comment: what is the data type of Sale field ?

Comment: Sale is a class

Answer (score 0):

Java streams will make short work of this task:

```
int indexOfMaxValue = IntStream.range(0, Sale.allValues.size())
    .filter(i -> Sale.allBranches.get(i).equals(branchEntered))
    .boxed()
    .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> Sale.allValues.get(i)))
    .orElseThrow();

double maxValue = Sale.allValues.get(indexOfMaxValue);
String elementOfMaxValuePostcode = Sale.allPostcode.get(indexOfMaxValue);
int elementOfMaxValueHouseNumber = Sale.allHouseNumbers.get(indexOfMaxValue);
```

Explanation:

1. Create a stream over the indices from `0` to `Sale.allValues.size() - 1`:

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, Sale.allValues.size()).boxed()
   ```
2. Filter the indices so only ones for the desired branch are kept:

   ```
       .filter(i -> Sale.allBranches.get(i).equals(branchEntered))
   ```
3. Now look up the sale values for these indices and find the maximum value. By running `.max` on the *indices* rather than *sale values* we get the maximum *index* as a result, eliminating the need to look it up in a second pass.

   ```
       .boxed()
       .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> Sale.allValues.get(i)))
   ```

   We use `boxed()` to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` so we can call `max` with a custom comparator. `IntStream` doesn't have the method we need.
4. If the branch has no sales there won't be a maximum sale. You can decide how you want to handle this edge case. See the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class for the methods at your disposal. For simplicity I chose to throw an exception:

   ```
       .orElseThrow();
   ```
5. Finally, the result of all of this is assigned to `indexOfMaxValue`.

   ```
   int indexOfMaxValue = ...;
   ```

Comment: I've added `.boxed()` to convert the `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>`. Does that fix the error?

Comment: Also, what if rather than max, I had to find the average of those filtered indexes?

Comment: Google "java stream average" to see how it's done, and if you still need help please post another question. It's too different to shoehorn into my existing answer.

Comment: I tried and ended up with one error. It has been posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71229739/how-do-i-find-the-average-of-filtered-elements-from-list-in-java , it would be great if you could help a little more.
Thank You.