# How do I find the average of filtered elements from list in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, average

I wish to find the average of sales by a particular branch in a given year. There is a list which has all the branches and all the years of sale. I've tried to use IntStream to filter the elements with the required year and branch but I'm unable to find the average, There is an error showing in indexOfSaleInTheYear.size(), and I am not sure if the average part code is correct. Please help. Thank You.

```
Scanner avgSale = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the year for average sale: \n");
    int yearEntered = avgSale.nextInt();

    Scanner branchNameForAvg = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the branch name whose average sale is to be found, case sensitive: \n");
    String branchNameEntered = branchNameForAvg.nextLine();

    Stream<Integer> indexOfSalesInTheYear = IntStream.of(0, Sale.allValues.size()).boxed()
            .filter(i -> Sale.allYears.get(i).equals(yearEntered))
            .filter(i -> Sale.allBranches.get(i).equals(branchNameEntered));
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < indexOfSalesInTheYear.size(); j++){
        sum += j;
    }
    double avgSaleFinal = sum/indexOfSalesInTheYear.size();

    System.out.println("The average sale for the year " + yearEntered + " is " + avgSaleFinal + ".");
    }
```

Comment: Is it a list of object or array? Please try adding sample of your dataset please

Comment: Please, could you paste the error code of the program

Comment: It is an array.
Error - Cannot resolve size in Stream.

Comment: `indexOfSalesInTheYear` is a `Stream`. You need to collect to a list first

Comment: I'm unable to convert it to a list because more than 1 data type is present, it is being converted to an object and not a list.

Comment: It looks like `Sale` contains separate arrays for values, years, and branches, instead of being a list of objects, with each object having a value, year, and branch?

Comment: Yeah! Sale has arrays of values, years, branch name, month, house no., and post code as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach it. Instead of separate lists of values, years, and branches, have a list of objects that contain these fields:

```
record Sale(int value, int year, String branch) {
}
```

Here I am using a `record` but if you prefer, need to have mutable `Sale` instances, or are using an earlier version of Java, you could adapt this code to use classes with ordinary getters and setters.

```
List<Sale> sales = List.of(
    new Sale(12, 2020, "east"),
    new Sale(15, 2020, "west"),
    new Sale(13, 2020, "east"),
    new Sale(16, 2020, "west"),
    new Sale(14, 2020, "east"),
    new Sale(17, 2020, "west"),
    new Sale(18, 2021, "east"),
    new Sale(19, 2021, "west"));

double averageOfSales(int year, String branchName) {
    OptionalDouble average = sales.stream()
        .filter(sale -> sale.year() == year)
        .filter(sale -> sale.branch().equals(branchName))
        .mapToInt(sale -> sale.value())
        .average();
    return average.orElseThrow(() ->
        new NoSuchElementException("no matching year and branch"));
}
```

You may want to simply return the `OptionalDouble` or throw a different exception; it all depends on how you want to handle the case where there are no values for the year and branch name provided. You may even want to just `return 0.0` or NaN or -1.0 or some other sentinel value in that case.

There is no need to sum the values yourself or divide by the number of values to find the mean since `IntStream` already has methods for finding the sum or average.

Keeping the different pieces of data broken out in separate, parallel structures is a common pattern among new Java programmers but it really goes against the concept of object oriented programming or even just abstract data types. You don't need to keep separate collections of simple values; you can invent your own types that encompass the value, year, branch, month, house number, post code, and whatever else you want to model as part of the domain of the data you're working with.

Comment: I am so sorry but I am really not able to understand the code, plus when I tried the code mentioned by you, many errors occurred, Can you please help me?
Should it be Intstream or just stream? And Sale is a class with lists in it.

Comment: @UtsavKothari If you want to have separate lists (sorry, not arrays), you'll need an `IntStream` to generate the indices, but if you have a single list of objects, you can just use a `Stream` of them, from the `.stream()` method of the list. I am showing you a different approach. I don't know what version of Java you have; if it is older, it may not have support for records.

Comment: Okay! I think I tried the other answer and it worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In your existing code, you are never iterating the `allValues` list.
Since you are using streams you can do this.

```
double average = IntStream.of(0, Sale.allValues.size()-1) // go up to the last index only
                .filter(i -> Sale.allYears.get(i).equals(yearEntered))
                .filter(i -> Sale.allBranches.get(i).equals(branchNameEntered))
                .mapToDouble(i -> Sale.allValues.get(i)) // now you have every sale value for yearEntered and branchNameEntered
                .average().orElse(-1); // or if not present, throw error, or get the optional, etc
```

Really you shouldn't have separate lists, you should have a list of Sale objects.

Comment: Thank You, your answer worked, I had another query. If we had to display the sales greater than  a particular amount, how would have we done that, with IntStream itself.

Comment: I'm trying if rather than equals(branchNameEntered), if it could have a condition for greater than an amount.... And this one is for values so there's just one single comaprison.

Comment: You just have one `filter` with your criteria. Then instead of `average` you can use `collect(Collectors.toList())`. You'll have all the values that meet your filter in the list and you can iterate with a for loop and do whatever you want with it. Or you can just replace the `average` with a `forEach` and procces the list in there